# (IF NOT EXISTS) in CREATE TABLE statement does not work

Tags: sql, ignite

When testing Ignite 2.6.0 (2018-07-16), it was found that `(IF NOT EXISTS)` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement did not work. Code show as below:

```
    Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/"))
    {
        try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement())
        {
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS City(id LONG PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + " name VARCHAR) WITH \"template=replicated\"");
        }
    }
```

After the first run is successful, an exception occurs again:

> Failed to execute SQL query [reqId=0, req=JdbcQueryExecuteRequest
>   [schemaName=PUBLIC, pageSize=1024, maxRows=0, sqlQry=CREATE TABLE IF
>   NOT EXISTS City(id LONG PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR) WITH
>   "template=replicated", args=[], stmtType=UPDATE_STMT_TYPE]] class
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Table
>   already exists: CITY  at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.ddl.DdlStatementsProcessor.convert(DdlStatementsProcessor.java:582)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.ddl.DdlStatementsProcessor.runDdlStatement(DdlStatementsProcessor.java:511)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.doRunPrepared(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1736)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.querySqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1671)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$4.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2035)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$4.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:2030)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2578)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2044)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.executeQuery(JdbcRequestHandler.java:456)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.handle(JdbcRequestHandler.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Is that the only place in your entire code that you attempt to create a city table? If you run the query in a query tool do you get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Checked the same, yes, it is an issue. I've created a Jira issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-10414.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem today and solved it by modified sql

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Timer"
```

to

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myCache.Timer"
```